# How do you reach the switches to open the chest in Eydie's Keep?

Tags: alwas-legacy

I completed all of the major dungeons in the game except the final one, but I can't seem to figure out how to reach the various purple diamond switches to open this chest.

It's almost as if the game expects me to have either an item that protects me from the purple spikes or switch gravity at will, but I haven't located any such items; the normal spell to prevent spike damage doesn't work on purple spikes.

Comment: I did manage to get the one in the room where you normally fall up, but the one behind the wall with spikes in it and the one in the room with the green tear and blue orb are still a mystery to me.

Comment: How much of the stuff in this map / guide do you have? https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2134510411

Answer (score 2):

One requires the green block upgrade that lets you hit the block and have it fly away from you and stick into a wall. You can then use it as a platform to jump up to the ladder leading to the diamond.

One requires either air-dashing over the spikes to land next to it and hit it, while gravity is normal, or the use of the lightning spell upgrade that shoots a bouncing projectile along with the straight-line projectile. The bouncing one can be bounced into the diamond even if your gravity is inverted.

One requires blowing up a wall, using the green block's final upgrade that causes an explosion when it's hit with the lightning spell. The game is not clear that "wreaking havoc" means destroying walls.